# Do I need to provide a hidden field for every property in my viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When using asp.net mvc do I need to provide a hidden field for every property in my viewmodel so that it is available when posted back. I'm thinking about properties that do not require user input such as `id`s or states etc.

```
public class viewmodel{
 string id - do I need a hidden field for this
 string name
 string something
}

public insert(viewmodel){
 I need to do something with the id here
}
```

Comment: yes, you do. if your viewmodel is posted back as an htmlpost it need the whole model to be present

Comment: @Emil ok, so i have a viewmodel that requires an id, but i do not have a hidden field with the id in yet i have noticed when debugging that the id is present in the viewmodel after posting. The id is in the url though.  Does that make a difference

Comment: if you are passing in a viewmodel with an id,  on post the id will comeback as null if it isn't represented on the view.  so your save changes will throw an error. for a new object it doesn't matter, but it is good practice

Comment: @emil Thats not my findings, which seems weird.  I certainly dont get any errors and the id is not present in any controls in the view

Comment: You will need to provide more code so that people can actually help you, but basically you´ll need to provide the id through hidden field if that id is necessary to complete the operation. If you do so, don´t forget to validate on server side that the user is allowed to do that operation in that model (hidden fields can be tampered). Regards.

Comment: If you referring just to a property named `ID` and you using the default routing (with a `.../{id}`) then that value is added as a route parameter (refer the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag you generating) and it will be bound when you submit. So you **do not** need a hidden input for that property.

Comment: As for other properties, that are not editable, then they should not have form controls. If you need those values when you submit the form, you get the data model again from the repository based on the ID